# Trying to Remove the Menu from Just One Page

Tags: css

Looking to remove the menu from just one page that I'm using as a static front page while the site is under construction. The site is sheisbiddy.com I thought the following code would work but it doesn't seem to be...

```
.sheiscoming #navigation {
display: none;
}
```

I believe this is the connected html but it's impossible to tell with this theme:

```
?>
#navigation ul li a                     { padding-top:<?php echo $of_option[$prefix.'header_navspace'] ?>px; }
#navigation ul li ul                    { top:<?php echo $of_option[$prefix.'header_navspace']+30 ?>px; }
```

Comment: Can you show the relevant HTML as well.

Comment: Please add the HTML so we can see if you structure matches your CSS.

Comment: I edited my question.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The page body has a page-specific class which can be used to target this elements on this *specific* page

```
.page-id-151 #navigation {
    display: none;
}
```

Comment: I thought that's what I did in the above code? Do I have to put the "page-id" for it to work?

Comment: The class you applied is not attached to the body. WP gives every page it's own class equal to its internal ID. So the page-id-151 will only ever apply to that specific page.

Comment: I see what you're saying... So what should I put instead? Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

Based on what's on the website already, this code works:

`body.home #navigation { display: none; }`

This only affects the navigation on the homepage, due to the class on the body.